# How to echo from array generated with SQL "SELECT SUM"

Tags: php

I`m new to PHP and coding in general. How can I echo out the number 27600 from the code below using PHP? The array was generated with Query:

```
SELECT sum(amount) FROM foo
```

---

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [sum(amount)] => 27600 ) )
```

Comment: Would suggest changing your query to `SELECT sum(amount) as total FROM foo` and then accessing it with `$var[0]->total`.

Comment: What @ChrisWhite says, but `$result[0]->{'sum(amount)'}`

Answer (score 0):

with single echo from MySQL OOP.

```
 <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT sum(amount) AS total FROM foo";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "My Total: " . $row["total"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```